# A good Tool for Desktop Test Automation

Tags: c#, automation, software-testing, visual-studio

As intern Student, I am starting software testing in a company where the most of testing is manually.
My manager want to include the test automation in the testing process and ask me if I can look for a good tool for desktop applications.

I mean with good that it doesn't require a high development skills, simple and easy to undestand and use.

The development environment is Windows 10, the used development Tool is visual Studio 2015 and the development language is C#.

I have searched in the net but the most of comparaisons are commercials.

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: *good* and *quality/price* are subjective. Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question with specific requirements.